# Fetch POST seems to be sending one thing, but another thing appears in DB

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, post, fetch

I'm facing this weird issue that I'm not even sure how to ask without posting the entire code. In broad terms, I have auth0 set for login and then I check the info that comes from it to see if that email is already in the database. If it is, I fetch GET from the server the remaining info pertaining to that user. If the user isn't already in the DB, the idea is to create the user there. I've been struggling with the asynchronous character of the whole operation and I'll get to it below just to see if someone has a better implementation to suggest, but the real issue I'm facing is that my fetch POST is supposed to send one thing to the DB, but when I check in MongoAtlas I see a different result.

Here's the code for the operation (please ignore the tag names in the return statements, as they're all styled components tags for mostly divs):

```
const Profile = () => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
    const {
        userId,
        setUserId,
        username,
        setUsername,
        email,
        setEmail,
        picture,
        setPicture,
    } = useContext(SearchContext);
    // newUserId and newUsername are set here as regular variables as a workaround to have them correctly assigned when creating a new user in the DB (due to React's asynchronous state variables)
    let newUserId;
    let newUsername;

    const createNewUserInDb = async () => {
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(newUserId);
        console.log(newUsername);

         await fetch("/users", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                userId: newUserId,
                username: newUsername,
                email: user.email,
                picture: user.picture,
            }),
         });
    };

    const currentUser = async () => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            // checking if user exists in db
            fetch("/users/" + user.email)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    let { userInDb } = data;
                    if (userInDb) {
                        console.log("from db");
                        setUserId(userInDb.userId);
                        setUsername(userInDb.name);
                        setEmail(userInDb.email);
                        setPicture(userInDb.picture);

                        // adding to localStorage
                        window.localStorage.setItem("userId", userInDb.userId);
                        window.localStorage.setItem("username", userInDb.name);
                    } else {
                        console.log("from auth0");
                        newUserId = uuidv4();
                        setUserId(newUserId);
                        if (user.given_name) {
                            newUsername = user.given_name;
                        } else {
                            newUsername = user.nickname;
                        }
                        setUsername(newUsername);
                        setEmail(user.email);
                        setPicture(user.picture);

                        // adding to localStorage
                        window.localStorage.setItem("userId", newUserId);
                        window.localStorage.setItem("username", newUsername);

                        // adding new user to DB
                        createNewUserInDb();
                    }
                });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        currentUser();
    }, [user]);

    if (!user) {
        if (isLoading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <>
                <LoginButton />
            </>
        );
    } else {
        if (!username) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <NameAndPicDiv>
                    <NameAndLogoutBtn>
                        <Name>{username}</Name>
                        <LogoutButton />
                    </NameAndLogoutBtn>
                    <ProfilePic src={picture} alt={username + "'s avatar"} />
                </NameAndPicDiv>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
};
```

The problem here appears in createNewUserInDb. The console.logs show that userId has no value assigned to it and newUserId and newUsername have the expected values. What I would be expecting to see in MongoAtlas is the values assigned to newUsername, newUserId, user.email, and user.picture (these last two come straight from auth0). But then MongoAtlas shows the following object:

```
{
userId: <user.email>,
notes: [],
songs: []
}
```

The weirdest part is that this was an old--albeit incomplete, as it would have the username as well--format for the user. Of course, it's being sent from elsewhere, from an older part of the code, the reader is guessing. But no, because if I comment out this fetch POST nothing appears on the server!

I'm really perplexed and don't know what to do about it. Any help will be very much appreciated! TIA

P.S.: With regard to the state variables and asynchronous code: I wasn't getting it to render first the "loading..." text and then the correct values before, when I used regular "let" variables instead of state variables. But now the state variables don't get their values updated right away, so I did those workarounds in order to be able to get them to the DB.

Comment: You may include the code related to the backend in your post above - the route handler and the database access code. It may have some clues regarding the issue.

Comment: Thank you for that, you just made me realize my endpoint was leading to the wrong handler, which I had left there for some obscure reason and should be commented out, but somehow I commented out the new one instead.